# Spliting cells in excel based on some parameter

Tags: excel-2007

I wanted to know who can the following content be split in to two cells:

if i have C:\Pgm\Win\a1.c 
   in one cell

how can i split it in to two cells

```
C:\Pgm\Win       a1.c
```

In my excel I have around 500 such rows.Is their any key availabe to do. I am using excel 2007.

Answer (score 0):

You can use formulas to do the split

Assuming first string is in cell `A1`, place these formulas
Cell `B1`

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","*",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))))-1)
```

Cell `C1`

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","*",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","")))))
```

Copy down for all data rows

Once these formulas are calculated, you can copy/paste values and delete the original data if required

Answer (score 0):

by using data to columns ....we can get...in to multiple columns...but it will not be an 100% solution